# Why is my pip not working even when i try to uninstall it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Everytime i use the pip command i get an error stopping me from using pip at all. I am using python 2.7.11.

Error:

```
C:\Users\cuerv\AppData\Local\Temp\aimbooster.py>pip install pip==20.3.3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cuerv\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\cuerv\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\cuerv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\cuerv\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: your error show this piece of code `f"ERROR: {exc}"` that is a f-string and those are python 3.6 features, so you are trying to run a py3 code with py2

Comment: You are not in fact using 2.7.11 as you expect; you are using 3.5 based on where the executable is installed. However, neither of those supports f-strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try `>pip -version` if nothing showing up go to https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-install-pip-on-windows/ .

If still not working try to install new version of python like python 3.8 and it should solve it.